# Azure Function data binding error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

My Azure Function (trigger - Blob, output - data bindung to MS SQL DB) throws error

`2017-04-03T17:17:33.475 Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobToDB. System.Net.Http: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Execution Failure     inner exception: The specified item 'TestEnt' is not found.)`.

I have TestEnt in my DB, connection string were verified few times.

Function code:

```
public static async Task Run(Stream myBlob, string name, IAsyncCollector<TestEnt> outputData, TraceWriter log)
{
        var R = new TestEnt();
        R.TestEntId = Guid.NewGuid();
        R.TestEntName = "Test";
        await outputData.AddAsync(R);
        log.Info($"ok!");        
}

public class TestEnt
{
    public Guid TestEntId { get; set; }

    public string TestEntName { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Post your bindings please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution - you need to fill the DB servername with web route (dbservername.database.windows.net not only dbservername)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lt8E.png)